# How do I separate out these sections? (scraping, but should be simple loops/foreach)

Tags: php, html, loops, simple-html-dom, scrape

I am using SIMPLE HTML DOM to scrape a website and I'm getting the following code...

**$GameSummary**

```
<dl class="ismSummary ismHomeSummary">
    <dt>Goals scored</dt>
    <dd><a class="ismViewProfile" href="#438">Gallas</a></dd>
    <dd><a class="ismViewProfile" href="#458">Defoe</a></dd>
    <dt>Assists</dt>
    <dd><a class="ismViewProfile" href="#443">Vertonghen</a></dd>
    <dd><a class="ismViewProfile" href="#447">Lennon</a></dd>
    <dt>Yellow cards</dt>
    <dd><a class="ismViewProfile" href="#438">Gallas</a></dd>
    <dd><a class="ismViewProfile" href="#439">Walker</a></dd>
    <dd><a class="ismViewProfile" href="#450">Huddlestone</a></dd>
    <dt>Saves</dt>
    <dd><a class="ismViewProfile" href="#433">Friedel</a> (3)</dd>
</dl>
```

I am trying to cut each section to its specific sections... I am trying to get the following info in the following order...

```
Heading1: Goals Scored
  Entry: Gallas
  Entry: Defoe
Heading2: Assists
  Entry: Vertongen
  Entry: Lennon
etc....
```

Here's the code I can get the headers with...

```
foreach ($GameSummary->find('dt') as $HeadingType)
  {
  echo $HeadingType;
  }
```

Gives me all headings... and to get content of each header..

```
foreach ($GameSummary->find('dd') as $PlayerNames)
  {
  echo $PlayerNames;
  }
```

---

What I am wondering is... How do I separate these into different groups? I can get all the headers and all the content separately, but I don't know how to get it so that each header contains its contents.

Any ideas how? It should be easy enough but my brain can't figure it out.

Thanks!

EXAMPLE AT: http://fantasypl.com/results.php

Comment: In short, do a `->find('dl')` and get all the children from that, then do a simple loop over those children: see if it's a dt or a dd, and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be, roughly:

```
   $i=1;
   foreach ($GameSummary->find('dl')->children() as $element)
    {
       if ($element->tag == "dt")  { echo "Heading$i: $element"; $i++; }
       if ($element->tag == "dd") echo "Entry: $element";

    }
```

[EDIT] Actual working code, from the comment below:

```
    foreach ($GameSummary->children() as $test) 
     { 

        if ($test->tag == "dt") { echo "Heading$i: ".$test->innertext."<br>"; $i++;} 
        if ($test->tag == "dd") { echo "Player: ".$test->innertext."<br>";} 
      }
```

Comment: Thanks.. It didn't work as-is, but I managed to get it to do what I wanted... or closer at least.. Heres what I used:

`foreach ($GameSummary->children() as $test)`
`{`
`echo $test->tag;`
`if ($test->tag == "dt") { echo "Heading$i: ".$test->innertext."<br>"; $i++;}`
`if ($test->tag == "dd") { echo "Player: ".$test->innertext."<br>";}`
`}`

Thanks - this saves me a lot of hassle. I think I can get it from here.

Comment: @CUlly - Thought so. I was just pointing you to the right direction.